# Flutter Firestore: The operator '[]' isn't defined for the class 'Object?'. - 'Object' is from 'dart:core'

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, product

I tried a number of things, and it keeps on showing errors:

```
children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                final data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                print(data);
                return ProductCard(
                  title: Text(data["name"]),
                  imageUrl: document.data()['images'][0],
                  price: "\$${document.data()['price']}",
                  productId: document.id, onPressed: (){},
                );
              }).toList(),
            );
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's my mistake the correct solution is:

```
children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((document) {
                final data = document.data()! as Map<String, dynamic>;
                print(data);
                return ProductCard(
                  title: "${data["name"]}",
                  imageUrl: data['images'][0],
                 // price: "\$${data['price']}",
                  productId: document.id, onPressed: (){},
                );
              }).toList(),
```